# Android TextView hidden when setting to single line scroll horizontal and center horizontal

Tags: android, textview, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to make a `TextView` to a fixed size, center the containing text, show the text in a single line and if the text is larger than the `TextView`, let the user scroll the `TextView` horizontal.

I almost managed to achieve this by setting this style for my TextView:

```
<style name="custom_text">        
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
</style>
```

The scroll works exactly how I want, the only bad thing is that the `TextView` is invisible when the screen shows up. To make the `TextView` visible it seems that I have to scroll the `TextView` in any direction. I tried to scroll the `TextView` from code in hope that the `TextView` will show up but no success.

How I can solve this?

Thank you!